# ASP.Net code behind wait a ADO.Net query to database returns for redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, redirect

```
I have a asp.net webform page who uses 2 google charts, I'm using Jquery Ajax to retrieve information from database to populate the charts, the query to retrieve the chart data takes a long time, in this time user can make a click in a link to redirect to another page, the redirect is very slow because wait querys return from database to do the redirect, how can I avoid this behavior?

I'm using Jquery Datatable plugin, when user click one row an javascript event is called
```

> function redirectToCampaignCreator(campaignID) {
>                   try {
>                       $.xhrPool.abortAll();
>                       redirecting = true;
>                       $('#multiCampID').val(campaignID);
>                       //window.location.href = "campaigncreator.aspx?Edit=True&CampaignId=" + campaignID;
>                       DoPartialPostBack("<%=btnCampaignEdit.UniqueID%>");
>                   } catch (e) {
>                   }
>               }

```
In this function I cancel the Ajax calls and do a __doPostBack(control, ""); to ejecute some code to save session values and then redirect
```

> ```
> protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, Even`enter code here`tArgs e)
>     {
>         if (IsPostBack)
>         {
>             if (Request.Form["multiCampID"] != null)
>             {
>                 View();
>                 Context.Response.Redirect("CampaignCreator.aspx?Edit=True", true);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

```
The redirect is slow because it's waiting querys return from DB
```

Comment: Clicking a link shouldn't wait for an AJAX call to complete.  Can you show code which demonstrates this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make your link client side instead of linking via redirect in the code behind?

Link to other page

Comment: Yes, I have used window.location.href in javascript code and the same results

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how you are using the code structure to manage such kind of tasks but if you want that your responsiveness to be free you can use async your c# functions.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx